# Replacing values in a data frame that don't begin with specfic character

Tags: regex, r

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
B<-c("L124","L234","Not","R23","NIMT","Lreg")
DF<-data.frame(A,B)
```

I would like to create a third column of values from Column B that begin with L. Any other values that do not begin with L would be listed as "Not L"

The final result would look like:

```
  A    B   C
1 1 L124   L124
2 2 L234   L234
3 3  Not   Not L
4 4  R23   Not L
5 5 NIMT   Not L
6 6 Lreg   Lreg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ifelse` and `grepl` for example:

```
ifelse(grepl('^L',B),B,"Not L")
[1] "L124"  "L234"  "Not L" "Not L" "Not L" "Lreg"
```